# Internal Server Error every time I push up my Wordpress Project to Heroku

Tags: permalinks, deployment, internal-server-error

We use Heroku to deploy our Wordpress project. However, everytime we push up it seems that all of the links bring the user to an Internal Server Error page. The homepage works.

Updating the permalinks (using the pretty permalinks for %postname%) solves this issue.

What we believe to be happening is that when a user hits: www.example.com/menu the permalinks haven't been updated yet, so the user sees an Internal Server Error. If you go to www.example.com/?p=2 you get redirected to www.example.com/menu but the page shows an Internal Server Error again.

Right now we have to update the permalinks **every time** we push up a new version of the site.

Anyone else have this problem and what did you do to solve it?

Much appreciation.

Comment: If you are pushing content then every time you _change domains_ you have to change the permalinks for embedded links. Is that what you are doing?

Comment: Yes, I am pushing from my local machine up to Heroku's server. The links are correct (i.e. it goes to the correct page) but the pages just show an Internal Server Error. However, the .htaccess file isn't changing after I update the permalinks. So, not sure what updating permalinks actually does to solve the issue.

Comment: Updating the permalinks causes the internal rewrite rules to be re-parsed. Look up `wp_rewrite` or `var_dump($wp_rewrite);` to get a good look at those rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being that the wp_rewrite was not flushed on the push to the Heroku server. So, what I ended up doing was creating a file in the root directory with the following code:

```
<?php
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
?>
```

Then I added a deploy hook for heroku via command line

```
heroku addons:add deployhooks:http --url=http://example.com/reset_permalinks.php
```

So, now when I deploy my application on the Heroku server, it runs the flush_rules() method and all is good. Thanks s_ha_dum!

Comment: Side note for folks deploying with git: in your post receive hook you can add ```wp rewrite flush``` to achieve this if you've got wp cli installed. https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/rewrite/flush/